# Sending mass emails - Newsletters

Tags: php, mass-emails

I have many customers who want to send them newsletters to its users.

I need to know the best way to do this service:
- Programming with PHP and PHPMailer?
- Using a tool such MailChimp, Campaing Monitor?
- Using libraries like http://www.phplist.com/?
- Using http://www.sendblaster.com/?
- Other?

What is the best way to do it?

It would be important (in the face of usuariois) the possibility of how Multilanguage, because users are Spanish, and have no knowledge of English.

Hope you can help me.

A greeting and thanks.

**Javier**

Comment: have u tried swiftmailer or a 3rd party service

Comment: How many emails are you sending? How many people do you have on your distribution list?

Comment: Do you just need to send email, or do you need an entire email platform?

Comment: "o you just need to send email, or do you need an entire email platform? – Mike Brant 4 hours ago"
I need send emails and need reports....
I need send customize emails by templates designed by my company

Answer (score 0):

I have used SendGrid to send emails, and the API is very straightforward.

The development community is also great:

http://sendgrid.com/

Comment: Their API is easy, but I wouldn't recommend them for large volumes of mail.  They seem to deliver quickly, but with 50,000+ e-mails a day, many will error out unexpectedly, often with the error that my credentials are wrong.  Simply retrying the send often fixes the problem.  Their tech support only knows the basics and isn't all that helpful.  I'm sure SendGrid is great for most folks, and they do meet our needs for the most part, but if I were to do it again, I'd use something else.

Comment: I must admit I haven't tried it with that many, I've used it with about 5,000 a day and it works great.

Comment: Hey.

Thanks for the info.

I see, the platform has cost SenGrid always, at least right?

And this platform can be customized to the clients? (corporate colors, logo, etc, e tc)

Should it be that EVERY CUSTOMER hire their own platform SendGrid not?

Are you multilingual platform? (I need it in Spanish).


I ask these things because before I need to know features PAY anything to tell my boss ...

Thanks and regards.

Javier